# SSRS Group by in the Report Header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am working on a simple SSRS Report.

```
Report Header     : AccountName
Report Sub Header : Group By CustomerName, Address
In the Detail,  I need Column1,Column2,Column3
```

I am able to show the Detail section in a Table Format. I am not able to set the Report Header and Report Sub Header. How to set the Report Header Group

I kept the SQL Fiddle for Sample set of Records.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d9d2/2

Sample Report Design

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to show report header and report footer ??

Comment: Only the Report Header. Not the footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments, and your further explanation I can tell you one thing, The formatting you have shown in your desired output is not possible.

What you want is a some text boxes along with a tablix, But as you have shown the sub-report header and client names and city fields in your report this can only be achieved using a List data region.

Table format shown can only be achieved from a tablix data region. But a hybrid report which may look like you have a tablix within your list region can be achieved as follows.(as in ssrs you cannot mix different types of data regions)

Obviously this is has very basic almost no formatting, you can spice it up a bit more with your designing abilities :)

[image]

Comment: I have the Page Header. I have done that. My question is how to Group by the records and split and display. In the Report Subheader Header to bring only CustomerName,Address and in the Detail section to show the remaining columns

Comment: What do you mean by Report Sub-Header Header? there is no such thing as sub-header in ssrs

Comment: I had that exp in Crystal Report. Anyways, i have attached the SQLFiddle for sample data and attached a design layout

Comment: This is not a tabular report this will be a List report. The header is going to be the header we have talked about before and rest of the elements, Column , "Sub-Header" , Name address City will be `textboxes` on that list, You will GROUP all this on Client Name.

Comment: I have added a List. Inside List, i have added a Table. I am getting an error message as. " The tablix has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members. "

Comment: See the way I have added `textbox` inside list region to make it look like a table, and I have already mentioned you cannot mix two different data regions inside eachother in ssrs.

Comment: Yes everything in this list is a textbox, SSRS has one really good feature that it has support for richtext. To activate rich text all you need to do is drag and drop a textbox inside the list region expand it to the entire list region and then add more textboxes like shown above to get the required format. and if this answer helped you please accept the answer thank you, good luck.